# Axure date text box components in browser does not display or display but add a use case is invalid

Tags: axure

Axure date of textbox is not shown in firefox, in Internet explorer does not display, can display in the opera and chrome, but!Click on the button of a judgment whether the controls the value in the empty case is invalid.What reason, how to solve